# Bing Map in Winrt

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps

I have a map and 15000 points in form of pushpins to be added to the map.

What I am doing is if the point lies in the visible region I add it to the MapLayer and add the layer to the map object.

This works fine but the panning is not that smooth.

I tried using IAsyncOperation to create the MapLayer but we cannot manipulate or create UIElement in IAsyncOperation.

Is there a way to create a Maplayer in background and replace the current maplayer.

Comment: Have you considered an approach that doesn't require adding all the pushpins at once (for example, by maintaining the list as those that would be visible)

Comment: Actually i simplified my problem the main objective is to implement clustering of pushpins I tried using virtual earth code snippet all is working fine but instead of plotting all 15000 points I plot only those that lie in the visible region because with so many UI elem in map object makes it difficult

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried binding the collection of pins to a `MapItemsControl`?  That should provide the UI virtualisation you need in order to make scrolling smoother.

EXAMPLE

XAML

```
<bm:Map Name="MainMapView" Credentials="{StaticResource BingMapsApiKey}" Margin="0">
    <bm:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyPoints}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}" />
</bm:Map>
```

where `MyPoints` is your collection of points, accessible in your view model